# cartopy Geodesics functions return MemoryViews of NaN arrays

Tags: cartopy

I have just installed `cartopy` from AUR for some geodesic calculations.

However, running

```
import cartopy.geodesic as geodesic
geodesic = geodesic.Geodesic()
geodesic.direct([[-26.77, 133.25]], 90.0, 100)
```

returns a `<MemoryView of 'ndarray' at 0x7f1139ed98c0>`, not an `ndarray`, and converting it to an actual `numpy.array` just gives me

```
array([[nan, nan, nan]])
```

Did I do something wrong in the installation, the initialization, or the use?

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the function correctly:

Looking at [the documentation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/cartopy/geodesic.html), the `direct` method, and the other methods in `geopy`, requires a **longitude, latitude** pair. Judging from your data, in particular if you wanted to have a point in the middle of Australia, you supplied a **latitude, longitude** pair: Your second value is bigger than 90°, but less than 180°.

Consider yourself lucky you were working on Australia, not on on Europe, you might have ended up with some bigger confusion if the calculation had given you twisted results around the coast of Somalia…